# How to automatically generate a csv file?

Tags: export

I need to daily update a list of members between civicrm and an external website on an other web server.

Is there a way/extension to do so from a smart group ?

First step would be to automatically generate a csv file.

It seems that I can't do this with CiviRules.

Second step, would be to export to a certain folder on an external web server.

Any experience or ideas?

Comment: Civireports can send a file automatically

Comment: Yep, to add to @petednz-fuzion's comment, set up a CiviReport with the filter of your choice, then under the "Access" tab, you can enter an email to send the report to. From there, check out Scheduled Jobs to configure the report to send the .csv file at whatever interval you wish.

Comment: thanks to both of you, I'll give a deeper try and report my (successful) process!

Answer (score 1):

Civireports can send a file automatically so set up a CiviReport with the filter of your choice, then under the "Access" tab, you can enter an email to send the report to. From there, check out Scheduled Jobs to configure the report to send the .csv file at whatever interval you wish

(pete with appreciation to Justin for writing most of the answer)

Comment: I've tried this way and it worked fine. My need actually is to start from the search builde because I need to grad value through relationships and the CiviReport tool is not sharp enough. Is there a way to create a CiviReport from the search builder or to programmatically send it per mail as csv?

Answer (score 1):

In addition to CiviReport, the [SQL Tasks](https://civicrm.org/extensions/sql-tasks-extension-configurable-recurring-tasks) extension can handle this.